# Repacking a struct in C/C++

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I would like to have a single definition for packed and unpacked structs.

The intent is to use reflection to translate one to the other. I do this currently by redefinition for performance versus wire formatting. It is necessary to have two definitions and memberwise copy between them to stop those rude segfaults.

It would be nice to not have two definitions in the spirit of DRY.

The C++ standard doesn't help which is unfortunate given how important packing is in wire formats.

I can't seem to find an implementation-defined way of doing this.

An `__attribute__((packed))` within a using alias or a `#pragma pack(1)` wrapping the same doesn't change the packing.

I was hoping there would be some alternative to wrapping stuff in YAM (yet another macro).

FWIW adding an alignment via the `using A __attribute__((aligned(256)))  = UnA;` does work on gcc v10.2. Changing the packing does not, sadly :-(.

Any clever trick I haven't found would be much appreciated.

--Matt.

Comment: You could do the wire-formatting on the fly and skip the packed struct. There are serialization libraries for that if you don't want to write it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Ted. That is not unreasonable. I have some interfaces to types that do things, such as logging, etc. It would be nice to have a solution that supports the definition of such structs. I could imagine iterating over the vars in the struct by reflection and copying bytewise things across to an appropriately sized struct as a proxy but I was hoping for something a little more "natural" I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It would be nice to not have two definitions in the spirit of DRY.

From a technical point of view it’s not a question of DRY. Two stucts with the same members in the same order but different padding are two distinct types. They have nothing in common because they may have different sizes and the members may live at different offsets. That’s as distinct as it gets.

So, separate definitions are unavoidable. To mitigate the source code duplication you could use the preprocessor. But you’re right of course, YAM is generally ugly, probably error prone, and altogether awful.

Instead take your preferred **code generator** and get rid of the duplication that way. The details depend on what that generator can do, of course. The most convenient solution for the programmer would be to write the non-packed struct manually. Something like this:

```
// header.hpp
namespace foo
{
struct Bar
{
    // members ...
};
}
```

Possibly you need some kind of tag (macro? custom annotation?) to mark the types that need a packed version. Then let the code generator parse that header (possibly using libClang/libTooling) and generate the rest:

```
// header_packed.hpp
namespace foo::packed 
{
struct __attribute__((packed)) Bar 
{
    // members ...
};

// conversion functions ...
}
```

The second best option is to write the relevant structs not in C++ but in some kind of DSL your code generator is familiar with and then generate all the C++ from that.

Comment: This is a fair answer and good answer, thanks. Though the compiler does allow us to change alignment through a type alias which while different to layout is nevertheless a kind of structural change. As I'm already relying on `hana`'s struct macros for reflection I suspect I'll YAM it but with your `::packed` suggestion. Then again, I do have code that parses 3rd party headers to put hundreds of structs into reflective form, so maybe I can turn that onto my own code with comment tags and codegen. All solutions seem a bit ugly. Alignment and packing could do with a bit more standard support.

Comment: Accepting this answer as there is no answer ;-)